# combining two if conditions in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I have a hash value:

```
request.session["flash"]["alert"]
```

I need to write an `if` condition for the above hash value like:

```
if request.session["flash"]
  if request.session["flash"]["alert"]
    #Do something
  end
end
```

I would like to combine both `if` condition in one line like:

```
if request.session["flash"] && request.session["flash"]["alert"]
  #do something
end
```

But this would throw a nil class error if `flash` is not there. How can I write two `if` conditions in one line, where if one condition passes it executes the other?

Comment: pretty sure that if request.session["flash"] && request.session["flash"]["alert"] should not throw a nil class error...  instead it should evaluate to if nil when flash is not present which will be evaluated as false

Comment: This line should work, the second condition is never run if `session['flash']` is nil

Comment: `if request.session['flash'].try(:[], 'alert')` should work

Comment: Are you saying that this _would_ throw a `nil` class error? Or are you saying that this _did_ throw a `nil` class error? If it _did_, what's the exact error?

Comment: Why don't you access flashes as you should, with `flash[:alert]`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you test your second snippet? As far as I know, Ruby uses lazy evaluation for if conditionals. The second condition will not get evaluated if the first one is false, so the [] method never even gets called on a nil object.

Source: http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2008/11/conditional-statements.html